# Where can i find an RSS or Atom feed of new or changed datasets in CKAN

Tags: ckan

This used to be part of the /revision page in CKAN <= 2.0 but looking at http://demo.ckan.org/revision or http://datahub.io/revision this seems to be absent now. Where can I find this now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a main Atom feed for the whole catalog at:

http://datahub.io/feeds/dataset.atom

Each group and tag also gets its own feed:

http://demo.ckan.org/feeds/group/data-explorer.atom

http://datahub.io/feeds/tag/lod.atom

And you can build your own using the same parameters as the package_search API call:

http://datahub.io/feeds/custom.atom?res_format=CSV

There use to be `<link rel="alternate">` tags on the main template but maybe these got lost during a frontend cleanup.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Is this in the documentation anywhere?